# Lagrange Remainder multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x,y)=y^2\cdot cos(2\pi x)$

Calculate the 2nd degree taylor polynomial at $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$:

$$
T_2[f,(1,1)]=f(x,y)+\langle \nabla f(x,y),\xi\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle\xi,Hessf\cdot\xi\rangle=-y^24\pi^2cos(2\pi x)\xi_1^2-4\pi\cdot y\cdot sin(x)\xi_1\xi_2-4\pi\cdot y\cdot sin(2\pi x)\cdot\xi_1\xi_2+2cos(2\pi x)=1+2\xi_2-2\pi^2\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2
$$

I believe my calculated Taylor Polynomial should be correct.
Now I am supposed to calculate the error.
Let $I=[0,2]x[0,2]$, show that the following estimate is true:

$$
\forall x\in I: \lvert f(x)-T_2[f(1,1)](x-(1,1))\rvert\leq\frac{16}{3}\pi^3+8\pi^2+2\pi
$$

There was a tip given to use triangle inequality but I decided to ignore that one for now.
I calculated the error:

$$
R_2=\lvert \sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert =3}\frac{D^\alpha f(\xi)}{\alpha !}\cdot(x-(1,1))^\alpha\rvert
$$

$$
\frac{\xi_2^2 8\pi^3sin(2\pi\xi_1)}{6}\cdot(x_1-1)^3+4\pi^2cos(2\pi\xi_1)\xi_2(x_1-1)^2\cdot(x_2-1)-2\pi sin(2\pi\xi_1)\cdot(x_1-1)\cdot(x_2-1)^2
$$

$\xi$ is between $1$ and $x_i$ and I want the term to reach its maximum.
Let $x_1=2$ and $x_2=2$
We now have:

$$
\frac{\xi_2^2\cdot8\pi^3sin(2\pi\xi_1)}{6}-4\pi^2cos(2\pi\xi_1)-2\pi sin(2\pi\xi_1)
$$

This can't ever reach $\frac{16}{3}pi^3+8\pi^2+2\pi$ right? So where did I go wrong, is it my derivation or something else? I don't really know how to go further and can't find any examples for the lagrange remainder for more than one variable.